# Filter Observable array of objects based on theirs observables

Tags: rxjs

I have an `Observable<Carrier[]>` called `carriers$`, this emits very rarely. Every `Carrier` has its `BehaviorSubject`, it holds whenever or not it is in cart.

This is as simplified as can be

```
interface Carreir {
  id: number;
  inCart: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
}

export class AppService {
  carriers$: Observable<Carreir[]>; // Let's ignore creation

  // Take all carriers and filter only those that are inCart
  inCart: Observable<Carreir[]> = this.carriers$.pipe(
    // I tried concatMap, mergeMap, flatMap, exaustMap, but 
    // This, unfortunately, does not use the Observable part of it.
    map(carriers => carriers.filter(carrier => carrier.inCart.value)),
  );
}
```

---

EDIT 1:

The reason for the `BehaviorSubject` in `Carrier` is so that the `carriers$` observable does not need to refresh filtering, sorting and other relatively computationally heavy tasks. The `Carrier[]` consist of 3000+ elements. Elements that are filtered out still can be part of the cart (ex.: filter a city, add some to cart, filter another city and add some more from the other city).

EDIT 2:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h4tk8e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: From the interface, it looks like for each carrier, there is a flag whether that carrier is in the cart. (I'm not sure why it's a BehaviorSubject and not a simple boolean ... I've not seen an interface defined like that before.) And it is not recommended to use the `.value` property of a BehaviorSubject in that way. Could you provide a bit more on what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe a stackblitz demonstrating your issue? We'd be happy to help.

Comment: @DeborahK The reason for the `BehaviorSubject` in `Carrier` is so that the `carriers$` observable does not need to refresh filtering, sorting and other relatively computationally heavy tasks.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How does that help? To prevent re-filtering/sorting on an Observable, you could use `shareReplay(1)`.

Comment: @DeborahK The `inCart` is actually never used for filters, I have over 3000 Carriers, that all must match type, address and few more. I don't want to re-filter if non of the core values change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, what you want is to filter all Carriers that are in the cart and emit them via the Observable `inCart$`. Carriers emit `true`, via `inCart` Subject when they are placed in the cart and emit `false` when they are removed from the cart.

You start from `carriers$` which emits an array of Carriers.

Now, a possible solution could look like this:

First you transform `carriers$` into a stream of booleans, which are the values emitted by all the BehaviorSubjects held in the `inCart` property of all Carriers.
This could be done like this

```
inCartBools$ = this.carriers$.pipe(
    // any time carriers$ emit we create an array of BehaviorSubject<bool>, one per Carrier
    switchMap(carriers => carriers.map(c => c.inCart)),
    // then we flatten the Observables to obtains a stream of booleans
    mergeMap(d => d),
  );
```

But a stream of booleans does not carry any information about the Carrier  which has emitted true or false, so we need to tweak a bit the code, so that we obtain a stream of objects containing both the id of the Carrier and the value of the boolean (so that we know whether the Carrier has been added or removed). This can be done like this

```
inCartBoolsAndCarrierIds$ = this.carriers$.pipe(
    switchMap(carriers => carriers.map(c => c.inCart.pipe(
      // rather than just a simple bool we return an object containing also the Carrier id
      map(v => ({id: c.id, v}))
    ))),
    mergeMap(d => d),
  );
```

Any time inCartBoolsAndCarrierIds$ emits, we need to either add the Carrier id to the cart or remove it, depending on the value of the bool. And we need also to keep memory of the array where we store the added ids. This can be done using the `scan` operator like this

```
inCart$ = this.carriers$.pipe(
    switchMap(carriers => carriers.map(c => c.inCart.pipe(map(v => ({id: c.id, v}))))),
    mergeMap(d => d),
    // we accumulate the ids of the Carriers in the cart via the scan operator, using a dictionary to store such ids
    scan((acc, val) => {
      if (val.v) {
        acc[val.id] = {id: val.id}
      } else {
        delete acc[val.id]
      }
      return acc
    }, {} as {[k: number]: {id: number}}),
    // eventually we return only the values of the ids
    map(dict => Object.values(dict))
  );
```

The final code can be checked in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2opcg9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts).

It looks a bit complex as solution but, if I have understood your problem right, it is a viable solution.

Comment: I actually wanted to get the `Carrier` rather than its ID, but it was trivial to solve, thanks. Do you think this is the right approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Your implementation is very much reactive and stateless, in the sense that you do not have any state stored in your component and you are using just Observable streams. At the same time you create one BehaviorSubject per each Carrier and I do not know if this can have consequences in your performance and memory requirements. You could opt also for a more stateful implementation like in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wvgz6o?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) (pls check correctness, since I wrote it fast). Check also if there are differences in performances.

Answer (score 0):

Without a working stackblitz, it's difficult to write the exact code for your requirements. But this is what I have, using tasks and completed tasks (instead of carriers and incart carriers).

I define the interface like this:

```
export interface ToDo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

Notice that `complete` is defined as `boolean`, not `BehaviorSubject<boolean>`.

The code to retrieve the todos for a user is this (which is probably not relevant to you.)

```
  // Todos for selected user
  toDos$ = this.userSelectedAction$.pipe(
    switchMap(userId =>
      this.http
        .get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${userId}`)
        .pipe(tap(todos => console.log('HTTP request issued:', JSON.stringify(todos))))
    )
  );
```

The code to filter the list to only those completed todos is this (which is the part that is hopefully relevant).

```
  // Todo's that are completed
  completedToDos$ = this.toDos$.pipe(
    map(todos => todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === true))
  );
```

Notice this takes the retrieved list of todos, maps the array and then filters each element of the array. This is very similar to the code you have.

You can find a working stackblitz of this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-completed-deborahk

If this doesn't exactly answer your question, feel free to fork this `blitz and adjust to better reflect your issue.